having value error while running xgb classifier using pyspark
I have a productionzed code, where im running at each group level, xgb classifier. If i run for 1 or 2 group it is working, but if run for 1--500 groups it is throwing Value error
Xgboost version : 1.5.2
Code: This part of the function
schema=T.StructType([T.StructField('stock',T.StringType(),True),T.StructField('re',T.StringType(),True),T.StructField('model',T.StringType(),True)])
    @F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def train_model(data):
        temp = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_jobs=1,scale_pos_weight = 1,random_state = 42,n_estimators = 50,\
            max_depth = 5,learning_rate=0.08,subsample = 0.9,min_child_weight = 4, \
                colsample_bytree=0.8).fit(data[features].values,data[target])
        data = data[group].drop_duplicates()
        data['model'] = str(pickle.dumps(temp),'latin1')
        return data

    df = df.select(group+features+target)
    bnb_models = df.groupBy(group).apply(train_model)
    return bnb_models

Error :
24/04/22 15:18:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 28.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 65) (spark-pi-prd-xxx-w-1.c.cp-gcd-prod-xxx.xxx executor 5): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [TASK_WRITE_FAILED] Task failed while writing rows to hdfs://spark-pi-prd-xxx-m/col400/models/All24_pred_spark/bnb_model.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dataproc/col400/col_spark/features/lib_bnb_qty_train.py", line 44, in train_model
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 730, in inner_f
    return func(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 1471, in fit
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  Expected: [0], got [1]


Looks like you may have data error. Try reviewing the the unique values of y. The error may exist in groups other than the groups it is working for.
